# Error with the return of a sorting words alphabetically method. Probably a logical error?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, return, nested-for-loop

I have a method thats supposted to go through an ArrayList of words and put them in order alphabetically using .compareTo(). However I get this message when the program is run

```
Exception message: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0
     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
     at ListSorter.sortWords(ListSorter.java:19) 
     at MyConsole.main(MyConsole.java:11)
```

I need it to return a list of words sorted alphabetically.
Ive tried taking out "newList" and replacing where you see newList with wordList but this message appears

```
Exception message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
     at ListSorter.sortWords(ListSorter.java:19)
     at MyConsole.main(MyConsole.java:11)
```

Any suggestions?

**The method in a class called ListSorter**

```
public ArrayList<String> sortWords(ArrayList<String> wordList) { // changed static void
    // TO DO #1: Sort the words in wordList in alphabetical order.
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int outter = 0; outter<wordList.size(); outter ++){ // takes 1 word in the list at a time
      for(int inner = 0; inner<wordList.size(); inner ++){ // compares it to all the other words in the list
         if((wordList.get(outter)).compareTo(wordList.get(inner))<0 ){ 
        // return i;
           newList.add(inner,wordList.get(outter));// adds current word to index of the inner loop
       }// end of if
   } // end of inner
    }// end outter
       return newList;
    
  }
```

**Whats currently in MyConsole**

```
 ArrayList<String> wordList = FileReader.getStringData("words.txt");
ListSorter newList = new ListSorter();
   // newList.setTextList(wordList);
    // TO DO #2: Call the sortWords() method and print the updated list.
System.out.print(newList.sortWords(wordList));
//newList.sortWords(wordList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling to Java newList array's size, in that case you cannot use *.add* with index.

You have 3 options:

1. Change newList to a array of String's

> ```
>   String[] newList = new String[x-size];
> ```

2. Use the .sort method of ArrayList.

> ```
>   wordList.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
> ```

3. Move the arrayList values to a treeSet (which use Comparable and is sorted)

> ```
>   Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>();
>   
>   for (String word : wordList) {          
>        sortedSet.add(word);
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

use **==0** instead of **<0**   :
         `if((wordList.get(outter)).compareTo(wordList.get(inner))<0 )`
compareTo returns number of common characters, fo You shouldn't get -1

Correct code :

```
public ArrayList<String> sortWords(ArrayList<String> wordList) { // changed static void
    // TO DO #1: Sort the words in wordList in alphabetical order.
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int outter = 0; outter<wordList.size(); outter ++){ // takes 1 word in the list at a time
      for(int inner = 0; inner<wordList.size(); inner ++){ // compares it to all the other words in the list
         if((wordList.get(outter)).compareTo(wordList.get(inner))==0 ){ 
        // return i;
           newList.add(inner,wordList.get(outter));// adds current word to index of the inner loop
           continue;
       }// end of if
   } // end of inner
    }// end outter
       return newList;
    
  }**
```